# Error with if statment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know why this code doesn't work properly: 
it should break when the input not 1 ,2 or 3

```
while True:
        try:
            aw = int(input('Number : '))

            if aw in [1,2,3] == False:
                print('give Number agian')
            else:
                print('correct')
                break

        except ValueError:
            print('please give a number')
```

Comment: `aw not in [1,2,3]`... Never use `== False` when there are other ways unless absolutely necessary (which I can't think of a reason to)

Comment: @cricket_007 - Would the alternative be `if not` instead of `False` ?

Comment: @Sveta I think those are equivalent. It's easier to read as `not in`

Comment: ok thanks for the answer